# Como guardar um result set dentro de um objeto arraylist em java?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, arraylist

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida em relação de como guardar o resultado de um select dentro de um objeto arraylist.
Eu tenho uma classe que faz a conexão com o Postgres e no método de conexão gostaria de executar uma query `select * from tabela limit 10` e guardar o resultado dentro do objeto arraylist.

Comment: Na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) tem um exemplo, basta adaptar para adicionar os dados na lista em vez de imprimir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A resposta é um código bem simples, vou usar essa classe aqui como exemplo:

```java
public class Usuario {
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String senha;

//construtores, getters e setter e bla bla bla
}
```

e a tabela deve conter essas informações, ou seja, criar uma coluna para cada dado(a coluna é chamada de campo, a linha é chamada de registro).
se você quer fazer a consulta sql com a mensagem `select * from tabela limit 10`, você deve fazer um código tipo assim:

```java
public List<Usuario> conexao(int limite /* no caso, vai ser 10*/) {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        st = conn.PrepareStatement("select * from tabela limit ?");
        st.setInt(1, limite);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        
        List<Usuario> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
            usuario.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            usuario.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            usuario.setSenha(rs.getString("senha"));
            
            resultado.add(usuario);
        }
        
        return resultado;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

observe que naquela parte do `while`, apenas instacia a classe e bota cada informação usando o objeto `rs`, se você não conhece os métodos usados do `rs` como o `getInt` e o `getString`, acesse a documentação oficial da oracle [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (infelizmente em inglês). Lembre-se de adaptar aquelas strings em cada `get` do `rs` pelo nome da coluna que está na tabela do banco de dados. Depois de criar o Usuario, apenas bota o Usuario no `resultado` e retornar o ArrayList.
Espero ter ajudado, se ainda não entender é só falar.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria, muito obrigada Lucas! Entendi perfeitamente.